Hilbert Transform of an integrable function on $[0,2\pi)$
This is Exercise 63 Chapter 14 from Frank Jones' book "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space".
Let $\mathbb{T}=[0,2\pi)$ and for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$
$$\widehat{f}(n)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)e^{-inx}dx, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
(a) Prove that for any $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ there exists a unique function $Hf\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ such that $$\widehat{Hf}(n)=-isgn(n)\widehat{f}(n),\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
(c) Prove that $\lVert Hf\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})}=\lVert f\rVert_{L^2{(\mathbb{T})}}$ if and only if $\int_{\mathbb{T}}fdx=0$.
(d) Assume $\int_{\mathbb{T}}fdx=0$. Prove that $H(Hf)=-f$.
(e) Let $0<a<1.$ Prove that $$H\left(\cfrac{e^{ix}}{1-ae^{ix}}\right)=-i\cfrac{e^{ix}}{1-ae^{ix}}$$
$$H\left(\cfrac{e^{-ix}}{1-ae^{-ix}}\right)=-i\cfrac{e^{-ix}}{1-ae^{-ix}},$$
and combine these to prove
$$H\left(\cfrac{1-a^2}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}\right)=\cfrac{2a\sin x}{1-2a\cos x+a^2}.$$
My work: I'm trying to follow the same argument as for the Hilbert transform on $\mathbb{R}$ (Exercise 48 Chapter 13): In this case, I defined, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $$Hf(x):=\mathscr{F}^{-1}(-isgn(\xi)(\mathscr{F}f)(\xi))(x),$$
where $\mathscr{F}:L^1(\mathbb{R})\to \{g\in C^0(\mathbb{R}) : \text{$g$ is bounded}\}$, $f\mapsto \mathscr{F}(f):=\widehat{f}$ is the Fourier transform.
Then, it follows that $Hf\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\widehat{Hf}(\xi)=-isgn(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi)$ and the existence and uniqueness follow by the bijectivity of $\mathscr{F}.$
Having defined $Hf$ we can show that $\lVert Hf\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=\lVert f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$ via Placherel's identity. Also, it follows that $Hf(f)=-f$.
Following this argument, I'm trying to define $Hf$ for functions $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ as $$Hf(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\left(-i sgn(n)\widehat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right)$$
for $x\in \mathbb{T}.$
With that definition, I believe part (a) is fine if I'm not wrong. Now, to prove (c), I'm trying to use Parseval's Identity: For $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\widehat{f}(n)\overline{\widehat{g}(n)},$$
so that $$\int_{\mathbb{T}}|Hf(x)|^2dx=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\widehat{Hf}(n)|^n=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|-isgn(n)\widehat{f}(n)|^2$$
$$"="\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|\widehat{f}(n)|^2=\int_{\mathbb{T}}|f(x)|^2dx=\lVert f \rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{T})},$$
where the third equality is the only equality that I believe is false. However, nowhere I did use that $\int fdx=0$.
Question: Could someone tell me if the Hilbert transform is defined correctly in both cases, and how to approach part (c) and guide me through the remaining parts?
Thanks!

I assume that $\operatorname{sgn}(0) = 0$
